# neo4j database size don't decrease when all nodes deleted

Tags: neo4j

I delete all of nodes and relationships in the neo4j browser with this command:

```
MATCH(a) DETACH DELETE a;
```

Now when I see my system info with this command:

```
:sysinfo
```

I see that my Logical Log and Total Store Size increased!
How can I decrease store size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the transaction logs retention policy.

If you are on Neo4j Community Edition, you can disable the logs fully :

Check https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/#config_dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy

Comment: I update line: dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=1 days to dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=false in neo4j.conf file but still store size increase when i deleted nodes.

Comment: did you restarted neo4j ?